# How to create add and remove input on click with JQuery

Tags: jquery, append

The input name (`comment_`) must be maximum to 20. It means that If I click 20 times Add comment and remove 5 comments and add 5 again, then should be `16,17,18,19,20` *(not 21,22,23,24,25)*. How I can repair that?

I've tried so far:

```js
var FieldCount = 0;
var x = $("#i_comment").length;
$('#add_comment_box').click(function(e) {
  if (x <= 21) {
    FieldCount++;
    $('#i_comment').append('<div class="in-section-50"><input type="text" class="in-75 mb-20" name="comment_' + FieldCount + '" id="field_' + 0 + '" required/> <a href="#" class="removeclass">Remove comment</a></div>');
    x++;
    $('#add_comment').show();
    $('add_comment_box').html('Add new comment');
    if (x == 21) {
      $('#add_comment').hide()
    }
  }
  return !1
});
$('body').on('click', '.removeclass', function(e) {
  if (x > 1) {
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
    $('#add_comment').show();
    $('add_comment_box').html('Add new comment')
  }
  return !1
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='add_comment_box' class='in-section-100'>
  <a id='add_comment' class='btn_add_c_a'>Add comment</a>
</div>
<div class='big-section d_b_i' id='i_comment'></div>
```

Comment: And what is the problem with your solution? What works? What doesn't work? Any errors in the console?

Comment: @Andreas See the question again.

Comment: `FieldCount` is not initialized. `var x = $("#i_comment").length;` is a complicated way for `var x = 1`; Ids have to be unique (`id="field_' + 0 + '"`).

Comment: The problem with `FieldCount` is visible in the console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: FieldCount is not defined` (just run your code in the snippet). After fixing that problem your code works -> Vote to close as off-topic because _this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error._

Comment: It seems you sometimes are using x and sometimes Fieldcount for the same purpose. I think the thing works if you remove x and use fieldcount instead.

Comment: @Andreas I've updated the question. How about the `comment_` and `FieldCount++`?

Comment: If the names always have to be consecutive, you will have to update them after removing or adding one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestion above, I think this is what you are looking for:

```js
$('#add_comment_box').click(function(e){
  console.log(e);
  comLength=$("#i_comment").children().length+1;
  if (comLength <= 20) {
   console.log(comLength) 
    
    $('#i_comment').append('<div class="in-section-50"><input type="text" class="in-75 mb-20" name="comment_' + comLength + '" id="field_' + comLength + '" required/> <a href="#" class="removeclass">Remove comment</a></div>');

    $('#add_comment').show();
    $('add_comment_box').html('Add new comment');
    if (comLength >= 21) {
      $('#add_comment').hide()
    }
  }
  return !1
});
$('body').on('click', '.removeclass', function(e){

  if ($("#i_comment").children().length >= 1) {
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    $('#add_comment').show();
    $('add_comment_box').html('Add new comment')
  }
  return !1
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='add_comment_box' class='in-section-100'>
  <a id='add_comment' class='btn_add_c_a'>Add comment</a>
</div>
<div class='big-section d_b_i' id='i_comment'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple logic i would suggest is, In your Add comment handler just add input with name as "comment_" + ($("#i_comment > div").length + 1). And then in remove handler go over each input and reset their count from 1 to 20.

To put simply, Here is the idea,

```
$('#add_comment_box').click(function(e) {
    if( $("#i_comment > div").length <= 20) {
      $('#i_comment').append('<div class="in-section-50 input-div"><input type="text" class="in-75 mb-20" name="comment_' + ($("#i_comment > div").length + 1) + '" required/> <a href="#" class="removeclass">Remove comment</a></div>');
    }
    return !1
});

$('body').on('click', '.removeclass', function(e) {
    if ($("#i_comment > div").length > 1) {
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        updateCount();
    }
    return !1
});

function updateCount() {
    $("#i_comment > div").each(function(key, value) {
        $(this).find('input').attr('name', 'comment_'+ (key + 1));
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't think TO wants 20 input fields with `name="comment_2"`

Comment: @Andreas After each addition this $("#i_comment").length + 1 will return next value. so when you first click you will get 2, in the next click you will get 3.

Comment: `$("#i_comment").length + 1` will always be `2`

Comment: I think CodeThing means $("#i_comment").children().length + 1